# get error class TestInformLogin has no attribute client

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests

I wrote this code for testing views in django
when I run it i get the following error

> response = self.clinet.get(self.inform_list_url)
> AttributeError: 'TestInformLogin' object has no attribute 'clinet'

```
from django.test import TestCase,Client
from django.urls import reverse
from KnowledgeManagement.models import Members , TblInform




class TestInformLogin(TestCase):
    def set_up_create_user(self):
        self.user = Members.objects.create(username='testuser',nationalCode = '1235' , mobileNumber = '094562', date_joined = '2021-11-22')
        self.user.set_password('12345')
        self.user.save()
        self.clinet = Client()
        self.clinet.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
        self.inform_list_url = reverse('inform_list')
        self.edit_inform_url = reverse('edit_inform', args= [1])

    def test_inform_list_GET(self):
        response = self.clinet.get(self.inform_list_url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response , 'inform_list.html')


    def test_edit_inform_GET(self):
        response = self.clinet.get(self.edit_inform_url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response , 'inform.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

self.clinet is defined in the set_up_create_user method, but I don't think you ever call this method.  That is why it is not defined.  This should fix it...

I'm editing this to show what it would look like using setUp method.

```
class TestInformLogin(TestCase):
    ''' Dont forget your doc string '''

    def setUp(self):
        self.set_up_create_user()

    def set_up_create_user(self):
        self.user = Members.objects.create(username='testuser',nationalCode = '1235' , mobileNumber = '094562', date_joined = '2021-11-22')
        self.user.set_password('12345')
        self.user.save()
        self.clinet = Client()
        self.clinet.login(username='testuser', password='12345')
        self.inform_list_url = reverse('inform_list')
        self.edit_inform_url = reverse('edit_inform', args= [1])

    def test_inform_list_GET(self):
        response = self.clinet.get(self.inform_list_url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response , 'inform_list.html')

    def test_edit_inform_GET(self):
        response = self.clinet.get(self.edit_inform_url)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code,200)
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response , 'inform.html')
```

Comment: well I don't call any of the methods. I just use them through command py manag.py test imagine that this class has 25 methods!! there is got to be a better way

Comment: See my edited updates

Answer (score 1):

Here your data is not set up when **test_inform_list_GET()** is called.

you can either change **set_up_create_user()** to **setUp()** or call **set_up_create_user()** inside **test_inform_list_GET()** and **test_edit_inform_GET()**

Comment: thanks! is setUp() a reserved name here?

Comment: setUp is a method that gets called before each test is ran.  There is also a tearDown method that gets called after each test is completed.  See unit testing documentation for more details.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Comment: I used the setUp  but still got the same error!!

Comment: Can you show your new code with setUp method implemented please

Answer (score 1):

you can change **set_up_create_user()** to **setUp()** and it will run before the rest of the methods or call the **set_up_create_user()** inside each method